# NASM: x86 to PPC - expression syntax error

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, powerpc, osx-tiger

I've been reading Assembly Language Step-By-Step (3rd edition; by Jeff Duntemann). I have a Linux box, a Lion box, and a (PPC) Tiger machine I can use. I've been writing small assembly programs with NASM on the Lion and Linux machines, and would like to do so on the Tiger one.

Mind you, I never expected this to be easy.

I'm not quite sure how I should change the code to work on PPC. I've so far ran into three `expression syntax error`s (lines 2, 3, and 14) that I can't figure out.

(I don't have a firm grasp of the PPC instruction set in the least.)

The code I'm trying to assemble is such: (ignore the line numbers)

```
1    SECTION .data
2        str: db "Hello, World!",0x10
3        len: equ $-str
4
5    SECTION .bss
6
7    SECTION .text
8        global start
9
10   start:
11       nop
12       mov eax,4
13       mov ebx,1
14       mov ecx,str
15       mov edx,len
16       int 0x80
17
18       mov eax,1
19       mov ebx,0
20       int 0x80
```

(I do realize that PPC is dying and there's not much point in figuring out its assembly, but learning is never a bad thing.)

Comment: NASM is only for x86/x86_64, it won't work with PPC so you have to use another assembler (for example the GNU assembler GAS). Also mostly everything else is also different for PPC - the instruction set and syscall method in particular - you're better off starting from scratch rather than converting existing code line by line.

Comment: (Though NASM does run.) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it would have been more proper to say that it only *targets* x86/x86_64. BTW to get a feel for how PPC code looks you can use `gcc -S hello.c` to have GCC output the assembly code of a C program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nasm` is an assembler for x86 / x86-64. You need to look at using the native (Mach-O ppc) `as` or gcc extended asm. It's not just a matter of changing opcodes - some directives will be invalid for ppc too. So you *will* need a firm grasp on PPC assembly.

It's also premature to say that [power](http://www.power.org) is dying. IBM POWER7 is still the "fastest" general purpose processor available. Also consider the Cell architecture and embedded markets.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote assembly for x86 (Intel i386). That is a different architecture than PowerPC (Motorola). See the PowerPC instruction set [here.](http://pds.twi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in1200/labcourse/instruction-set/)

Additionally you need to use assembler which understands the PowerPC instruction set, gnu `as` for instance.

Edit: Without a basic understanding of the instruction set (which is often fundamentally different for each architecture) you will find it impossible to write assembly.

Comment: I was mostly wondering if NASM used the same assembly language across platforms (doesn't make terribly much sense, now that I think about it).